# How can I disable 2FA for a specific iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

How can I make a certain iPhone not require 2FA when logging in with my Apple ID? I have a phone that never asks me when I login with my Apple ID, but on a new phone it will ask for it every time I log back in.

Is it based on how long you're logged in for it to trust the phone or something?